# SWRevealViewController switching between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a problem with `SWRevealViewController`. In my app I have a long chain of `UIViewControllers` connected to a single `UINavigationController`. After adding a side menu and setting the "reveal view controller push controller" segue for cells I see only `ViewController`s connected with a segue. I can't move between my `UIViewControllers` in the chain any more. And navigation bar is missing. Is it possible to use a side bar and `UINavigationBar` at the same time?

Comment: can you share your 'storyboard image' so that i can help you better

Comment: Sure. I've made couple notes for better understanding. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwVoN9mpO-R_azJNcWJubGVVU2JOQUd6bng0WVgzR05Xc2dJ/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: did you use in attribute Inspector. Top Bar (Opaque Navigation Bar)?

Comment: Museer Ansari, yes I did

Comment: Please check my case http://screencast.com/t/2OHQHjjFpXSj

and calling like this 
in did select row method 
`if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if let lvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabViewController") as? TabViewController {
                self.revealViewController().setFront(lvc, animated: true)
                self.revealViewController().setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.left, animated: true)
            }
        }`

Comment: No :( I've tried this and it's still only one screen and no nav bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your image I think you have to add another navigation controller before the `C****** S****** View Controller` or the view controller you want to go
the reason is that there is no `UINavigationController` before the `C****** S****** View Controller` and that's why Navigation bar is hidden and you can't move

Comment: I've tried to do so. I can go to the next 'ViewController' in the chain, but I don't have "Back" button

Comment: you have to implement your back button then

Comment: I'm sorry, I checked document outline in interface builder and I have back button inside navigation item, but it's invisible. How can I make it active?

Comment: if it is invisible you can just create your      Try This                                      `UIBarButtonItem * button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button;  `                                                                                                                                                    `-(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
}`

Comment: or if you want this code in Swift or you want to change title with Image then ask me

Comment: Yes, adding back button manually and setting segue to the previous ViewController made the trick! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Looks like every 'NavigationController' has its own stack of 'ViewControllers'. And when you switch to another 'NavigationController' connected with a segue from side menu, you can't go back because there are no 'ViewControllers' in the stack of new 'NavigationController'. Am I right?